# IMAP seems to be slowing down my mail client

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

Recently, started using IMAP in mail client (Thunderbird) instead of POP.

This has resulted in sluggish responsiveness. It frequently pauses and I have to wait for it do things. For example, if I try to drag a message into a folder usually there is a long pause of 5-10 seconds before it completes the move.

Is there any way to avoid this? Should I just go back to POP?

Comment: Thunderbird's CPU usage is high when the client builds your email library. Have you added a new account recently?

Comment: @user598527 Yes, the IMAP is configured for the new account. However, it has been sluggish since I installed it for several days, so I don't think it is a one time thing.